# How to clear errors in angular controls

Tags: angular

It's really clear how to set custom errors in angular:

```
this.form.controls['field'].setErrors({same:true});
```

But it is not clear on how to remove that. Anyone know how to do this? Any alternatives?

Comment: I don't know if you'll get notification of my answer when I delete and undeleted my answer. So just to inform you :)

Answer (score 13):

Just set erros to null

`this.form.controls['field'].setErrors(null);`

Answer (score 0):

```
this.form.controls['field'].updateValueAndValidity();
```

this is the method documentation:

```
/**
  * Re-calculates the value and validation status of the control.
  *
  * By default, it will also update the value and validity of its 
 ancestors.
  */
 updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf, emitEvent}: {onlySelf?: boolean, emitEvent?: boolean} = {}):  void {... }
```

Comment: What does this do? When should I call it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following when you want to remove the custom error:

```
delete this.form.controls['field'].errors['same']
```

you might need/want to update the validity after this with:

```
this.form.controls['field'].updateValueAndValidity();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line to remove the custom error.

```
this.form.controls['field'].updateValueAndValidity();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below-mentioned method and pass control name, key means error name and value will be true or null to set or remove the error from the controls respectively.

```
errorInFields(control: AbstractControl,key,value){
let errors  = control.errors;
if(!errors){
  if(value == null){
    control.setErrors(null);
  }else{
    let error = {};
    error[key] = value;
    control.setErrors(error);
  }
}else{

  if(value == null){
    if(errors.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      delete errors[key];
    }
    let errorsKey = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(errors);;
    if(errorsKey.length <= 0){
      control.setErrors(null);
    }else{
      control.setErrors(errors);
    }
  }else{
    errors[key] = value;
    control.setErrors(errors);
  }
}}
```